# Is there a more efficient way to write jQuery code that will change the scale of an element while another element is hovered?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a more efficient way (if there is one) to write some code that will allow me to change the scale of elements '**B**' and '**C**' while '**A**' is hovered, and vice versa. I've managed to get it to work in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcavind/567nezkm/), but I'm hoping there's a better way to go about it. Down the road, I'd like to be able to  incorporate this into a carousel, or something similar without having a plethora of code bogging down the site.

Here's what I have so far, jQuery-wise:

```
$("#element1") // select your element
.hover(function(){ // trigger the mouseover event
    $("#element2, #element3") // select the elements to shrink
        .css({ transform: 'scale(0.9)' }); // change the scale
}, function(){ // trigger the mouseout event
    $("#element2, #element3") // select the same element
        .css({ transform: 'scale(1)' }); // original scale
});
$("#element2")
.hover(function(){
    $("#element1, #element3")
        .css({ transform: 'scale(0.9)' });
}, function(){
    $("#element1, #element3")
        .css({ transform: 'scale(1)' });
});
$("#element3")
.hover(function(){
    $("#element1, #element2")
        .css({ transform: 'scale(0.9)' });
}, function(){
    $("#element1, #element2")
        .css({ transform: 'scale(1)' });
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a class (for example, `circle`) to each of your elements instead of an id , and then use the `.not()` function in jquery to select all elements except the hovered one and then scale them accordingly.

> This way you won't have to write separate JQuery code for hover on each element , the below code can be used when you want to scale all other elements except the hovered element.

---

**Code Snippet**:

```js
$(".circle")
  .hover(function() {
    $(".circle").not(this)
      .css({
        transform: 'scale(0.9)'
      });
  }, function() {
    $(".circle").not(this)
      .css({
        transform: 'scale(1)'
      });
  });
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}
.shape1,
.shape2,
.shape3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
}
.shape1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.shape2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.shape3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#element1,
#element2,
#element3 {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class='circle' id="element1">
    <div class="shape1"></div>
    <!-- /shape2 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /element1 -->

  <div class='circle' id="element2">
    <div class="shape2"></div>
    <!-- /shape2 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /span-one-third -->

  <div class='circle' id="element3">
    <div class="shape3"></div>
    <!-- /shape3 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /span-one-third -->
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, @stark

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) jquery function if they all have the same direct parent. I would have to look at your HTML to provide a more accurate answer.

You can also filter the results of `.siblings()` using selectors like this:

```
 //inside hover
 $(this).siblings('[id^="element"] ');
```